# Security aspects of changing _clean_input_keys($str) function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, input

I've created a form by codeigniter `form_helper` and the output form (`method : post` )in my html page had som elements like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" name=" category['download']" value="1">
```

but when I submited the form codeigniter gave me this error :

```
Disallowed Key Characters error.
```

I searched and found the problem is probably with  `_clean_input_keys($str)` function in `system/core/input.php` and when I changed it from this :

```
if ( ! preg_match("/[]^'[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

to

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

my problem fade away , I mean I added  `[]` and `'`   to the allowed characters , Now  dose it make a security problem for my project or not ? if yes , what is correct way ?

Comment: category['download'] should be category[download] you are in html, there is no need to define a string with quotes

Comment: Your `name` should look like this `name="category[download]"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
category['download']
```

to

```
category[download]
```